# How to determine if an object stopped moving or left the frame

Tags: opencv, emgucv

Every tutorial, sample or blog I have read show various ways to track a moving object in a frame, as long as it is *moving*. This has become ubiquitous.

What I have been trying to figure out is how to ***determine if the object stopped moving or actually left the frame***. When using background separation, when an object stops moving it becomes part of the foreground and as such "disappears". It "reappears" when it moves again. As far as I can tell the same behavior exists when an object leaves the frame, it just "disappears". For example the following code fragment demonstrates this:

```
**BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 _fgDetector = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
CvBlobDetector _blobDetector = new CvBlobDetector();
CvTracks _tracker = new CvTracks();
CvBlobs _blobs = new CvBlobs();**

private int FindAndTrack()
{
    CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(_analyzeMat, _smoothedFrame, new System.Drawing.Size(3, 3), 1); 

    #region use the BG/FG detector to find the forground mask

    _fgDetector.Apply(_smoothedFrame, _foregroundMask);

    #endregion use the BG/FG detector to find the forground mask

    _blobDetector.Detect(_foregroundMask.ToImage<Gray, byte>(), _blobs);
    _blobs.FilterByArea(_minimumAreaValue, int.MaxValue);

    _tracker.Update(_blobs, 0.01 * _scaleValue, 1, 5);
    return _tracker.Count;
}
```

I am no longer sure that background separation may be the answer.

What would give a definitive indication of a object leaving the frame?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

Place tracker.update as condition for if loop if condition fails your object of interest has left the frame.
If you want to detect if object has moved or not then compare x & y values of bounding box of object with previous x & y values of bounding box if values are same than object has stopped moving else it has moved